# wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow not installing all updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I would like to install updates from command line

OS : Windows 7 x64

I ran

wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow

and in the log it says "No feature Update available"

[image]

but it never installed the following updates, please help me figure out how i can the following using command

[image: office and windows 7 updates that were not installed]
[image: Optional Updates that were not installed]

Answer (score 2):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc720477.aspx

> As I remember it, when an update check occurs a cookie is stored that
>   prevents a new update or check for 1 hour. So, you should use the
>   `/resetauthorization` switch, along with `/detectnow`, like this:

```
wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this works:

From an elevated prompt, stop the update services with

```
net stop wuauserv
```

Delete the contents of C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution, then restart update services.  (net start wuauserv).
Then, run wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow.