# windows 10 wuauclt.exe not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I was using wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow till now

and now on my Windows 10 Enterprise Build 1511 it's not working

Is there an alternative way to detect and install updates using command?

I know it installs them automatically but i have no control over that schedule, i am not looking to defer them. I just want to be able to install if they are available on demand.

### My Test

I had this machine where updates were installed on 4/11 so on 4/13 it was just sitting there not installing the updates, I ran the above command it did nothing
Then i went to PC Settings manually click Check Updates and it started installing.

So instead of having to manually check i would like to do that via command

Comment: what is not working? Why do you install them via commandline? Windows 10 install updates automatically by default.

Comment: how often it's checking when there is new updates?

Comment: @magicandre1981 at this moment i know there are updates avaialble but windows 10 updates is not just triggering it so dont konw what it's waiting for or how often does it check. I would like to trigger this on demand so i can be done with it and need this done via command so i can schedule it

Comment: [You are having the identical problem on Windows 7.](http://superuser.com/questions/1061931/wuauclt-exe-detectnow-updatenow-not-installing-all-updates)  If it helps I can confirm this command still works on Windows 10.  Are you connected to a domain and/or is Windows set to download from WSUS?

Comment: i am not connected to Domain, these download directly from microsoft i forgot about that win 7 completely, i am running some more tests, thanks for confirming that same command works for you on Windows 10, maybe i am missing something, i am going to try to disable UAC etc

Comment: It works with UAC enabled on my system.  You should generate the same logs you generated on Windows 7, see if that pinpoints the problem, or it might shove you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 5):

wuauclt.exe /detectnow has been deprecated according to ["Features Removed or Deprecated in Windows Server 2016"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/deprecated-features) for Windows Server 2016 and likely by extension Windows 10.

> The wuauclt.exe /detectnow command has been removed and is no longer
>   supported. To trigger a scan for updates, do either of the following:
>
> Run these PowerShell commands:
>
> ```
> $AutoUpdates = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate"
> $AutoUpdates.DetectNow()
> ```

Comment: doesn't work for me today. 'PS C:\Windows\system32> $AutoUpdates.DetectNow()
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8024A10B
At line:1 char:1
+ $AutoUpdates.DetectNow()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: @arthurbrogard what Windows Build version are  you using?

Comment: @monterery harris  v1909 b 18363.592

Answer (score 0):

The complete Windows 10 way to deal with updates sucks. I suggest you to use the tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-update-minitool.380535/) which allows to search for updates and also select which updates you would like to be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do: 
> • **Check
>   for updates** 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • Hiding unwanted updates
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `WUAUCLT.EXE` has been replaced by `USOCLIENT.EXE`

Thanks to Jean-Yves Moschetto from [anvole.com](https://www.anvole.com/en-us/corp/news/articleid/121/wuauclt-no-more-working-on-windows-10-please-replace-with-usoclient-exe).

The command to run now is

```
USOCLIENT.EXE RefreshSettings StartScan StartDownload StartInstall
```

Sean Conroy from [I don't know, read the manual](https://www.idkrtm.com/windows-update-commands/) has got additional info & command line options.